# JPA - hibernate.use_identifier_rollback throwing NullPointerException

Tags: hibernate, jpa, identity, entitymanager

I have the following `Main` class where I am trying to call the `remove()` of `EntityManager` using the `hibernate.use_identifier_rollback` property set to `true` in `persistence.xml` file.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myUnit");    
        
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        
        Foo foo= em.find(Foo.class, 2L);
        em.remove(foo);
        Long fooId = foo.getId();
        
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close(); 
    }
}
```

Having the following property throws the `NullPointerException` when the `em.remove(foo)` method is called.

```
<property name="hibernate.use_identifier_rollback" value="true" />
```

Following is the complete stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.resetIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5362)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireDelete(SessionImpl.java:877)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.delete(SessionImpl.java:809)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.remove(SessionImpl.java:2714)
    at mock.Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

Following is my Foo entity:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    //...
}
```

What could be the reason behind that and how to resolve the issue?

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: @SternK Hibernate 6.0 development version